# TinyMce troubles with hyperlink absolute url

Tags: url, hyperlink, tinymce, absolute

I added tinyMce editor in my textarea input form.
Unfortunately I have troubles sending hyperlink absolute urls.

I create dynamically the pages within a php CMS.

I can start tinyMce and I can send formatted text.
When I try to add url, the final result is not the absoluted url I added, but it is preceded by another string url, as showed under:

```
//Input url: www.example.it, will process the following result:
//http://www.myDomain.example/folder/\"http://www.example.it\"
```

Because of that the final link doesn't work, even if in the tinyMce preview all seems to be good.

I followed the indications written in the official website FAQ to set the initial values:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  relative_urls : false,
  remove_script_host : true,
  document_base_url : 'http://www.mydomain.example/folder/'
});
```

Comment: have you tried relative_urls: true,  ?

Comment: yes, I think the problem is inside my domain hosting setup, and I can't manage it, unfortunately. I am trying a different approach using plugins as linkyfyjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really nasty gotcha. Notice the escaped quotes around the url you entered? You have magic_quotes set to on! I've just spent 2 hours tracking this bug down *again* so I figured I'd better document it on the site.

Before saving the url to the database add:

```
if  (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    foreach ($row as &$value)
        $value = stripslashes($value);
```

This will get rid of the escaped quotes and allow the browser to recognize an absolute url.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I was far from stack for a while.U was right! Although that I solved the trouble by installing the last version of php, the problem was exactly the one described by you: magic quotes! Some years ago I used them to sanitize inputs, but, when their use become deprecated, I totally forgot about them! Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah - my host keeps alternating between having them on and off by default so I'd forgotten about getting rid of them, too!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that could help, you can use the documentation to create a function that handles this issue
[TinyMce urlconverter_callback](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/#urlconverter_callback)

hence you can add

```
relative_urls: true
remove_script_host: false
urlconverter_callback : 'customURLConverter'
```

and For the **customURLConverter** function
you may use something like that

```
function customURLConverter(url, node, on_save, name)
{
    var checkURL;
    var urlPrefix;

    // Get the first 7 characters of the string
    checkURL = url.substring(0, 7);

    // Determine if those characters are coming from the image uploader
    if(checkURL === "/system")
    {
        // prefix the incoming URL with my domain
        urlPrefix = 'https://www.example.com';
        url = urlPrefix.concat(url);
    }

    // Return URL
    return url;
}
```