# user-submitted hyperlinks in a text editor are broken by quotes

Tags: php, wordpress, url, tinymce

I run a wordpress job board, on which users can post job listings and the job description input uses tinyMCE.

The problem: when some users insert hyperlinks into the body of their listing, the link is broken in the published ad, with some added quote marks inserted, eg: http://example.com/en became ””//example.com/en/”””
This happened once in a while, not for every ad and not for every link within an ad.

I recently found out that what seems to be happening is that the following characters %E2%80%9D are getting inserted within the links, and these encode double quote marks. Say the page on my site where the link is posted is *https://example.org/mypage/*, and that the link the user is trying to post is *https://usersite.com/theirpage/*, the resulting URL will be some weird mash-up of the two:

```
https://example.org/mypage/%E2%80%9D/usersite.com/theirpage/
```

From some googling it seems this might be caused by users copy/pasting hyperlinks from word or webpages.

I'm trying to find a way to automatically prevent this so I don't have to manually clean up tens of links a day. I figure there must be something I can change in the tinyMCE settings.

I have found seemingly related questions from several years ago that suggest it could be to do with magic quotes ([example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187673/22-double-quotes-added-to-url-out-of-nowhere) [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342747/tinymce-troubles-with-hyperlink-absolute-url) ) but I don't know how to implement the proposed solutions as I'm no php pro.

How would you go about solving this for a wordpress website? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, it will help immensely if you can provide links to examples. Also, from my understanding, people post jobs on a page that uses TinyMCE for the description field, this data is then stored in WordPress - is this correct?

Comment: Hi @DallasClark, I've edited to add a specific example. As for your question, to be honest I'm not entirely sure how the whole thing works.

Comment: Hi, do you have a link to the page where people post the ads please? Before I answer, I just want to check your config/setup.

Comment: Not a convenient one unfortunately as you'd have to register on the site to actually see it, sorry. Is there specific info I can extract for you? thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is occurring because users are inserting content from Word with double quotes (”), but they're not your standard double quotes.

Standard: " (straight)

Non-standard: ” (on an angle)

The encoding you’ve inserted (%E2%80%9D) indicates a character that cannot be parsed (understood), and encoding has been used to transfer the character through databases and web servers. This encoding provides the double quotes on an angle (”).

In JavaScript, the decoding of this encoding in demonstrated in the following:

```
decodeURI('%E2%80%9D')
”
```

*I don't believe* this is an issue with TinyMCE.

**How to fix the issue?**

There are a few solutions, and they’re going to require some development knowledge. Two safe options that come to mind are:

1. Before the content is stored, remove these characters using PHP string replace
2. If the issue is how users are inserting the content into TinyMCE, it might be worthwhile adding TinyMCE Link Checker (https://www.tiny.cloud/tinymce/features/link-checker). Note, this is a premium feature.

*Disclaimer, I'm affiliated with Tiny. The comments above are of my own.*

Comment: Thank you, do you have suggestions on the actual php code? I presume this is a function that could go into my code snippets/functions.php file? I could perhaps figure out the actual string replace function but what I'm really unsure about is how to make sure it is called/triggered at the right time/place. thanks

Comment: also, wouldn't removing those characters leave problematic links with a concatenation of my site address and the inserted url? In my example above, we would end up with: https://example.org/mypage//usersite.com/theirpage/